# How to Embed part of a page?

Tags: jquery, html

I need some help in regards to embedding a particular page and a particular section of a page into my own HTML page.
 The url is
http://www.bom.gov.au/products/IDR023.loop.shtml#skip

[image]

I tried using an Iframe.. it was too fiddly.. tried using Jquery to target that Div.. it didn;t work...

any suggestions? or help?
I even tried to get the full HTML and recreate the page... it doesn't work..

Ta

Vik

Comment: From the source code of the page you can see that the radar is actually a image with its source being constantly updated. You could just implement the javascript that generates the new value of `src` and update your own `<img>`. You can get the bottom legend by putting a screenshot on your page below the image.

Comment: Have you asked the BOM for permission to use part of their page?

Comment: They give their data freely on their FTP site... plus I want to keep their name on it.... so it should be fine...

Answer (score 0):

i went through the website...
thats more like an image the url is `http://ws.cdn.bom.gov.au/radar/IDR023.T.201705050242.png` but the radar isn't part of the image tho so source codeing may be a little difficult..  i think it works with thier satellite or something..  just ask the owner for permission to use it.

Comment: *"i think it works with thier satellite or something"* - Or maybe their *radar*?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't pretty, but it should get you started:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./IDR.browser_check.v08.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td id="overlayCell" rowspan="2" width="514" class="imagePanel"><div id="overlay" style="position: absolute; top: auto; left: auto; z-index: 0; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; background-color: transparent; display: block; width: 512px; height: 557px; background-image: url(&quot;http://ws.cdn.bom.gov.au/products/radar_transparencies/IDR.legend.0.png&quot;);"><img name="animation" id="animation" class="animation" border="0" height="512" width="512" src="" alt="Radar images"><div id="backgroundDiv" style="width: 512px; height: 512px; background-color: transparent; position: absolute; z-index: -3; left: 0px; top: 0px; background-image: url(&quot;http://ws.cdn.bom.gov.au/products/radar_transparencies/IDR023.background.png&quot;);"></div><div id="locationsDiv" style="width: 512px; height: 512px; background-color: transparent; position: absolute; z-index: 7; left: 0px; top: 0px; background-image: url(&quot;http://ws.cdn.bom.gov.au/products/radar_transparencies/IDR023.locations.png&quot;);"></div><div id="rangeDiv" style="width: 512px; height: 512px; background-color: transparent; position: absolute; z-index: 2; left: 0px; top: 0px; background-image: url(&quot;http://ws.cdn.bom.gov.au/products/radar_transparencies/IDR023.range.png&quot;);"></div><div id="topographyDiv" style="width: 512px; height: 512px; background-color: transparent; position: absolute; z-index: -2; left: 0px; top: 0px; background-image: url(&quot;http://ws.cdn.bom.gov.au/products/radar_transparencies/IDR023.topography.png&quot;);"></div></div></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./IDR.loop.v12.0.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's the diff between my version of *IDR.loop.v12.0.js* and the original:

```
bash$ diff <(curl -s http://www.bom.gov.au/scripts/radar/IDR.loop.v12.0.js) IDR.loop.v12.0.js 
0a1,18
> ID = 'IDR023';
> Km = 128; // Standard 64km, 128km, 256km or 512km radar picture.
> nImages = 6;
> theImageNames = [
>   "http://ws.cdn.bom.gov.au/radar/IDR023.T.201705050248.png",
>   "http://ws.cdn.bom.gov.au/radar/IDR023.T.201705050254.png",
>   "http://ws.cdn.bom.gov.au/radar/IDR023.T.201705050300.png",
>   "http://ws.cdn.bom.gov.au/radar/IDR023.T.201705050306.png",
>   "http://ws.cdn.bom.gov.au/radar/IDR023.T.201705050312.png",
>   "http://ws.cdn.bom.gov.au/radar/IDR023.T.201705050318.png"
> ];
> function isDST(t) { //t is the date object to check, returns true if daylight saving time is in effect.
>   var jan = new Date(t.getFullYear(),0,1);
>   var jul = new Date(t.getFullYear(),6,1);
>   return Math.min(jan.getTimezoneOffset(),jul.getTimezoneOffset()) == t.getTimezoneOffset();  
> }
> isdst = isDST(new Date());
> state = "Vic";
308c326
<   if (page_type !== 'national' && page_type !== 'include'  && page_type !== 'defence') {
---
>   if (false) {
506c524
<   var numbElements = document.tog.elements.length;
---
>   var numbElements = 0 //document.tog.elements.length;
636c654
<       if (theImages.length > 1) {
---
>       if (false) {
653c671
<       if (theImages.length > 1) {
---
>       if (false) {
1564a1583
>   return true;
2747a2767,2768
> 
> launch();
```

It runs at the time of this posting, but will eventually break because `theImageNames` is hard-coded.  I got the array by typing it in the console of the original website, which is possible because a lot of the vars are global.  Changing this and maybe some date logic should get you closer.